# How to UV Map using an Image as the texture source

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-coordinates, vector-mapping

I am busy with a project and have been struggling for a while with this and was hoping that someone knows the solution to my problem which is with the mapping/ uv mapping.

Attached is 3 images each respectively named **Figure A, Figure B and Figure C**
[image]

The model (which is not mine and is just being used as an example) has been created and is perfectly symmetrical.
**Figure A** show the left side of the model and **Figure B** the right side.

My problem has to do with **Figure C** and its reflection on the right side.

What needs to happen is that the the the texture on **Figure C** needs to be on the right hand side due to the fact that it is hidden. Is this possible?

Any help with this will be highly appreciated

If you need any clarification please do not hesitate to let me know. 
I am anxious to get this project up and running but don’t fully understand UV mapping in blender that well yet.

Comment: so you have a a mirrored UV map (like figure A) but need to uv map an image with a projection like figure C?

Comment: Some clarification Questions first ;)

"My problem has to do with Figure C and its reflection on the right side." --- Do you want a reflection of the texture or do you want to map the C texture to the Purple Faces?

And what do you mean by "due to the fact that it is hidden"